# How to find how many seconds are elapsed in a minute?

Tags: java

I am generating OTP which is changed every 30 seconds. So I just want to check how many seconds are elapsed in a minute to generate OTP only if 10 or more seconds are remaining to complete a minute.

Comment: Can you show your code? What variables and data types do you have to work from?

Comment: why not just use your operating system to schedule the job to run every minute (or some other scheduling mechanism)? Use existing stuff rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Maybe something like `Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().withSecond(0).withNano(0).plusMinutes(1)).getSeconds()` - but why does it need to be down to the minute?

Comment: You might want to learn about [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use it in `Java8`:

```
60-LocalDateTime.now().getSecond()
```

or

```
60-ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

Comment: int seconds = LocalDateTime.now().getSecond();
   int remainingSeconds = 0;
   if (seconds < 30) {
    remainingSeconds = 30 - seconds;
   } else if (seconds > 30) {
    remainingSeconds = 60 - seconds;
   }

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` for a particular moment. Use `Instant` (or `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`). While you will get results here, using that class in this context is misleading/confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
(int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)%60
```

Edit:

If you use Java 8:

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond()%60
```

Since epoch time start from 00:00:00 of 1-1-1970, with these codes you can get the second elapsed from last minute.
Of course you need to subtract the value from 60

Comment: Instant.now().getEpochSecond()%60, is also working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the number of seconds *left until the next minute*, you actually need:

```
60 - (int)(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)%60;
```

Comment: Could be several seconds off based on intercalation of leap seconds over time.

Comment: @JimGarrison I respect that you put a comment in for why you downvoted. It's a fair counterpoint.